# Prisma GraphQl how to correctly update fields

Tags: sql-update, prisma, mutation, prisma-graphql

I'm working with GraphQl and Prisma for the first time and I am trying to make an update function in my resolver mutation file but I have been struggling with it. I have done some research but the things that I am finding don't work for my code. I always end up with errors. Could someone help me with this?

Schema:

```
type Service {
    id: ID!
    createdAt: DateTime! 
    updatedAt: DateTime! 
    name: String!
    cost: Float!
    description:String
    hours: Int!
    minutes: Int!
    postedBy: User!
}

type Mutation {
    postService(name: String!, cost:Float!,description:String!,hours: Int!, minutes: Int! ): Service!
    deleteService(id: ID!): Service!
    updateService(name: String!, cost:Float!,description:String!,hours: Int!, minutes: Int!): Service!

}
```

mutation resolver:

```
function updateService(parent, args, context, info) {
    return context.prisma.mutation.updateService({
        cost: args.cost,
        name: args.name,
        description: args.description,
        hours: args.hours,
        minutes: args.minutes,
        postedBy: { connect: { id: userId } },
        where: {
            id: args.where.id
        }
    }, info)
}
```

query in prisma playground:

```
mutation{ 
updateService( 
   name: "Update test"
    where:{
    id :  "ckaz82x01aqq50a42fkrz3uxu"
        }
){id
 name 
 hours 
 minutes}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above mutation that you have posted, you have only passed `name` and not all of the variables.

Where as in your schema below, `cost`, `description`, `hours`, `minutes` are required.

```
updateService(name: String!, cost:Float!,description:String!,hours: Int!, minutes: Int!): Service!
```

Could you check if that's the error that you are receiving? If so, pass all the parameters and run the mutation again.

Comment: True I changed it but I get this error `"message": "Unknown argument \"where\" on field \"updateService\" of type \"Mutation\"."`

Comment: The mutation `updateService(name: String!, cost:Float!,description:String!,hours: Int!, minutes: Int!): Service!` doesn't contain any `where` variable which is why the error. You would have to add the where to the mutation in the `schema.graphql` as well.

Comment: Hi Ryan , I've put where in it like you suggested  `updateService(name: String, cost:Float,description:String,hours: Int, minutes: Int, where:ID!): Service!` but now I get this error --> `"message": "Cannot read property 'updateService' of undefined",` but I don't understand the error. Thank you for responding